# libgdx: How do I convert touch coordinates to 3D point on camera NEAR plane?

Tags: camera, libgdx

I'm a libgdx *NOOB* - apologies if this is an obvious question..

Using libgdx I have set up a Perspective camera, looking at origin (camera near = 1f, far = 300f). Viewport extends across the entire screen.

Basically, I would like to know how to convert a 2D screen coordinate (x,y) to the 3D world coordinate (x, y, z) where the Z value is clamped to the camera's *near* plane.

I think I should use the [camera.getPickRay](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/Camera.html#getPickRay-float-float-) method to get a picking ray for the screen coordinate. I should then get the intersection point of this ray and the camera's near plane to get the world coordinate of the point on the near plane.

I thought that the resulting *Ray object's* **origin** property was the near-plane intersection  point I was after, but this doesn't seem to be the case.

Am I on the right track?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Camera#unproject()](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/Camera.html#unproject-com.badlogic.gdx.math.Vector3-) returns, depending on the z-value, the value between the near (z=0) and far plane (z=1), see the [javadocs](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/Camera.html#unproject-com.badlogic.gdx.math.Vector3-). [Camera#getPickRay()](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/gdx/src/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/Camera.java#L253) sets the `origin` member to the unprojected value at z=0, thus on the near plane, see the [code](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/gdx/src/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/Camera.java#L253). If you don't need the ray (including the `direction`) then you don't have to calculate the pick ray, instead you can call the `unproject` method directly.

```
Vector3 pointOnNearPlane = camera.unproject(new Vector3(touchX, touchY, 0f));
```

Likewise, for the point on the far plane:

```
Vector3 pointOnFarPlane = camera.unproject(new Vector3(touchX, touchY, 1f));
```

Comment: Thanks @Xoppa - that worked for me!  (BTW, I'm digging your [libgdx tutorials](http://blog.xoppa.com/basic-3d-using-libgdx-2/))